# May a woman go to a mixed beach wearing a modest swim suit?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty

Is it permitted for a woman to go to a mixed beach in let say Spain in the summer wearing a modest swim suit, such as Aqua Modesta?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at our [tour] for some useful information about the site.

Comment: Is there a specific standard of modesty that Aqua Modesta conforms to? Are all of their swimsuits equally modest? Are they the same in terms of modesty as the woman's regular clothing and just simply designed for use in water?

Answer (score -2):

According to [Rav Moshe Feinstein](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14678&st=&pgnum=119), a woman should be stringent and not swim with a male lifeguard. There’s technically nothing wrong there, as he’s “busy with his work” - implying in an ordinary case, where there are men on the beach who are *not* lifeguards, the leniency would not apply and it would be strictly forbidden.

Comment: Since that teshuva is discussing a place that's women-only, except for the lifeguard, how sure are you that he's referring to swimming specifically wearing a modest swimsuit?

Comment: I don't see the _kal vachomer_. Swimming with a male lifeguard is putting yourself in a situation where you might need him to touch you. (Yes, it'd be _pikuach nefesh_, but you're putting yourself in the situation.) Swimming with men is not putting yourself in such a situation. I'm not saying R'MF would permit swimming with men (and doubt he would): I'm merely saying that your _kal vachomer_ doesn't seem to hold.

Comment: I hear what you are saying and the sort of kal vachomer, although the issur of hirhurim and shmiras anyim do not apply to non Jews, so a Jewish woman who is going on holiday to let say Portugal where there are likely to be no Jewish men, whilst making an effort not to go where there are many men, wearing a modest swimwear, would there be any basis for leniency?

Comment: Is there any indication in the responsum that he's talking about *modest* swimsuits like this question is? Maybe the leniency for lifeguards is  when she's wearing an *immodest* swimsuit, but if she's wearing a modest swimsuit it would be permissible even if there are other men. If anything I would argue that the responsum is indicative of an *immodest* swimsuit since his argument is that it's not pritzus because it's a place designated for women and therefore like her own house.